# Java Swing on Client's PC

Tags: java, swing, testing, desktop-application

I am new to Java Swing developing and I already made a simple app, I want to run this app on client's PC(a Computer that is going to use the app but doesn't need to install JDK), should I use NSIS Installer or should i do something else?

Comment: `Java` app requires `JVM` instance to run on. You do not need `JDK` - `JRE` is enough.  See https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/jvm-vs-jre-vs-jdk

Comment: See the list of Java JEP documents to learn about the jlink and jpackage tooling available in the latest Java versions for packaging a JDK runtime with your Swing app. You’ll need to learn about the [Java Platform Module System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System). Otherwise, if you have access to the user’s computer, install a JDK there. Get a JDK from vendors such as Adoptium, Amazon, Azul Systems, BellSoft, Pivotal, SAP, Oracle, Microsoft, Red Hat/IBM, etc.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.